# What to do with an open question like this?

Tags: discussion

The question https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40476/relationship-between-jesus-his-father is about the trinity, yet does not specify what kind of answer it would like (trinitarian or non-trinitarian). Is it too broad, too opinion-based, or is it ok that this will attract differing answers? It does make a great place for collecting different views on the subject, but is it off-topic because there clearly is no answer that could ever be accepted as "the answer" since the question is totally open to both views?

Answer (score 4):

You flag it (or vote to close if you have sufficient rep), as in its current form it is both too broad and primarily-opinion-based (it doesn't really matter which one you choose). It is definitely off-topic as is.

Comment: And as a general symptom, would you say I can recognize such questions by finding that the spectrum of possible answers is broad (like, in this case, different contradicting answers)?

Comment: @kutschkem The spectrum of possible answers being broad will mean that it is "primarily-opinion-based". Having several questions that are quite separable or any question that will require a significantly long answer to be considered in any way adequate is where things tend to be thought of as "broad".

Comment: @curiousdannii I like the question I will post an answer. Didn't it say this is a discussion.  HERE GOES...